# about image larger bug use jquery.zoomtoo.js

Tags: jquery

sorry , i bad in english . but this bug confused me 1 month,maybe more time.help anybody.thanks all.
it was strange,sometime work,sometime not work.
i use jquery.zoomtoo.js in my web site.
http://mall.mannay.com/category-128/product-62 
when mouse after product image,image will large (if work).
but,sometime it not work, large picture run page top.
if it work will,please F5 one again, BUG will happen.
SO strange for me ,i would try so many time.maybe jquery.zoomtoo.js bug.
if can't fixed,i have to drop this,and try another jquery to work.

Comment: final,i found some error,or not perfect.   if image loading not complete , zoom image will get error top,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found if image parent div not setting height,will gei some error.
it like that,if image is large ,and image loading not complete.the zoom image will get error top,it will not change,to be a defined.